# Binding input from Azure blob in function app using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a csv file in azure blob storage that I would like to open and get certain data based on user input. I have two problems:

1) Empty AzureWebJobsStorage value in local.settings.json

I tried to input binding using *AzureWebJobsStorage* but the value seems empty. I'm not sure how I can what value I should edit in local.settings.json. Hence, getting this error:

> Executed 'Functions.HttpExample' (Failed, Id=3a9309d6-7019-4de6-a8d2-43c89921b0f6)
>   [18-Feb-20 9:40:36 AM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpExample. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Value cannot be null.
>   [18-Feb-20 9:40:36 AM] Parameter name: connectionString.

I updated the value with connection string of my storage account. It still did not work.

function.json :

```
{
  "type": "blob",
  "direction": "in",
  "name": "container_name",
  "path": "blob_name/file_name.csv",
  "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
}
```

Am I using the correct variable names above? As I also received another error :

> The specified blob does not exist.

But the blob exist in the storage.

2) How do I display all data inside csv from this (assuming the above issue has resolved)

This is my current code in `__init__.py` :

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputblob: func.InputStream) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    section = req.params.get('section')
    bound = req.params.get('bound')
    km_location = req.params.get('km_location')
    location = req.params.get('location')
    if not section:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            section = req_body.get('section')

    if section and bound and km_location:
        #pass the following user input to the following function and use them to retrieve remaining info
        #from csv (stored in blob) to user.
        result(section, km_location, bound, location).getResult() 

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {section}, {bound}!")
```

Comment: I think the blob is not found because my AzureWebJobsStorage is empty. But when I added connection string in AzureWebJobsStorage, it did not work either.

Comment: The path should be `container name/blob name` and why your `name` property is `container_name` and in your code is inputblob.

Comment: What value should I put in `name`? What about AzureWebJobsStorage value? What value does it takes?

Comment: Any update now? Could you solve it with my way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the definition about property in `function.json` you could refer to this doc: [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=python#configuration).

**name** is the variable that represents the blob in function code. It should be same in the function code, and could be any variable you want.

The below is my test `function.json`, you could also refer to the sample in the link I provide.

```
{
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "test/test.csv",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "in"
    }
```

And about how to read csv file, you could refer to my function code.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import csv
import codecs


def main(req: func.HttpRequest,inputBlob: func.InputStream) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    reader=csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(inputBlob,'utf-8'))
    for line in reader:
        logging.info(line)

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
             status_code=400
        )
```

Here is my test result, hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

[image]

Comment: Hi May I know if you are debugging in local environment? the statement of [import azure.functions as func] shows error of module cannot be found while debugging in vs code, any suggestion plz.